# About transforming dates in R 3.1.0 in OSX 10.9.2

Tags: r, excel, macos, date

I have a column of dates containing 2 different formats, that is DD/MM/YY and D/M/YY. Because the Microsoft Excel (for mac 2011, 14.3.9) recognised those dates labelled D/M/YY as M/D/YY in part of the variables, the output dates become incorrect.

Then I turned to R and tried to transform the column into a format of "DD-MON-YYYY", where MON is short form of months, like 01-Jan-2014. The column is something like this:

```
> head(date, 10)
       date
1  17/12/96
2   27/6/07 
3   21/6/13
4   24/7/13
5   17/7/13
6   16/7/13
7  13/10/99
8   20/2/97
9  14/12/96
10  19/6/13
```

I used the `format` function

```
format(date,"%d %b %Y")
```

And the output was

```
Error in format.default(structure(as.character(x), names = names(x), dim = dim(x),  : 
  invalid 'trim' argument
```

I have also tried the `lubridate` package with no success.

```
> library(lubridate)
> dmy(date)
[1] NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Is there any simple method to transform the date?

Comment: It might be useful for you to edit your question and include the output of `dput(head(date))`. It seems to me like your dates character strings rather than `Date` objects. Assuming `date` is a data frame, perhaps `format(as.Date(date[[1]], '%d/%m/%y'), '%d %b %Y')` might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transform your strings to objects of class date, e.g.

```
as.Date("17/12/96", "%d/%m/%y")
[1] "1996-12-17"
```

and then apply your format

```
format(as.Date("17/12/96", "%d/%m/%y"), "%d-%b-%Y")
[1] "17-Dec-1996"
```